# Ruby Mechanize get elements with specified text

Tags: css, ruby, mechanize

I am trying to parse the contents of a website using mechanize and I am stuck at a point. The content that I want to parse is inside a `li` tag and is not always in the same order.

Lets suppose that we have the following where the order of `li` tags is not always the same and some times some may not even be there at all.

```
<div class="details">
  <ul>
    <li><span>title 1</span> ": here are the details"</li>
    <li><span>title 2</span> ": here are the details"</li>
    <li><span>title 3</span> ": here are the details"</li>
    <li><span>title 4</span> ": here are the details"</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I want is to get only the `li` details where the `span` text is for example `title 3`. What I have done is the following which gives me the details from the first `li`:

```
puts page.at('.details').at('span', :text => "title 3").at("+ *").text
```

Is there a way to do what I want using mechanize or should I also use other means?

Comment: If you want you can do this using nokogiri.. If you want,I can try for you..

Comment: Mechanize as I have read and seen is working with nokogiri. The `page` that you see can be treated as a nokogiri object in which you can search. Instead of for example `css_at` you write just `at`

Comment: Humm I just found that.. What's the problem with your code? If I get to know that,I can probably think my one.. :)

Comment: As I said the problem is that it gives me the first `li` whereas I want the one that has as `<span>` text `title 3`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
page.search(".details").at("span:contains('title 3')").parent.text
```

Explanation: 
With **at** you can use css or xpath selector. In order to make more readable and similar to your approach, this answer use css selector, but the problem is that CSS cannot perform selection based on text. Thanks to Nokogiri, you can use use JQuery selector, so the **contains** methods is allow.

The selection get the span element, so if you want to get the li element parent, you can use **parent** methods and then get the text easily.

Comment: It worked like that. The only think that I changed is that I used `next` instead of `parent` to get the details part. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a jQuery selector, it's a css selector.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're looking to do this using Mechanize (and I see one of the comments recommend using Nokogiri instead) you should be aware that Mechanize is built on Nokogiri, so you're actually able to use any/all Nokogiri functionality through Mechanize.

To show you from the docs at http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html

> Mechanize.html_parser = Nokogiri::XML

So you can accomplish this using XPath and the mechanize page.search method.

> page.search("//div[@class='details']/ul/li[span='title 3']").text

This should be able to give you the text for the li element that you're looking for. (unverified with .text, but the XPath does work)

You can test the XPath here: http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/51c5142c-dbef-4206-8fbc-1ba567373fb2

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner `css` approach:

```
page.at('.details li:has(span[text()="title 3"])')
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment I think you are looking for something like below.

> *As I said the problem is that it gives me the first li whereas I want the one that has as  text title 3*

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-eotl
<div class="details">
  <ul>
    <li><span>title 1</span> ": here are the details"</li>
    <li><span>title 2</span> ": here are the details"</li>
    <li><span>title 3</span> ": here are the details"</li>
    <li><span>title 4</span> ": here are the details"</li>
  </ul>
</div>
eotl

node = doc.at_xpath("//div[@class='details']//span[contains(.,'title 3')]/..")
node.name # => "li"
puts node.to_html  
# <li>
# <span>title 3</span> ": here are the details"</li>
puts node.children
#<span>title 3</span>
# ": here are the details"
```